# Migration from log4j 1.2.17 to log4j 2.17.1

Tags: java, log4j

I have a legacy code that uses lots of internal APIs from `log4j 1.2.17` and I'm trying to upgrade to latest version `log4j 2.17.1` using [these](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.17.1/manual/migration.html) steps.

However there is lot of code that I simply can't find the direct replacement for such as

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
```

and so on.

P.S. I have added `log4j-core-2.17.1.jar` and `log4j-api-2.17.1.jar` to the classpath.

Comment: A complete `org.apache.log4j.Appender` that does not rely on the functionality of `AppenderSkeleton` (except getters/setters) will work in Log4j 2.x. Unfortunately most custom appenders rely on `AppenderSkeleton` methods which are no-ops in `log4j-1.2-api` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.java)).

Answer (score 0):

You will find these in the log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1 jar

Comment: And they are no-ops, :-).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz , this is the Bridge jar approach right? I was trying not to use this approach. Do I really need this jar?

Comment: No, there is `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractAppender` and many other helper classes to rewrite your appenders as native Log4j 2.x [`Appender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender.html)